# How to do stress testing for a Liferay webpage?

Tags: testing, liferay

I have a webpage in a Liferay 5.2.3 site, in order to view this page the user shoulde be logged in.

i tried JMeter for stress testing but i stopped after i had this [issue here](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/639622) ("invalid authentication token"). What other tool i could use to do stress test without facing the authentication issue (with example of script if its available).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I managed to log in and then when sending POST requests to the server I only received 403. What I have done is that I set the auth.token.check.enabled to false in the portal-ext.properties.

```
auth.token.check.enabled=false
```

But be careful. The Portal Authentication Token was implemented to prevent Cross Site Request forgery, as explained here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF).
On a production environment set the property back to true.

More about that on the liferay site: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authentication+Token

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure but you could try Grinder, it supports jython as scripting language, although i dont have a working script example at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter but you have to use its proxy to record your actions (login included).

Please see [JMeter proxy step by step](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

Comment: I tried that i had the issue stated above "invalid authentication token" even when i record my actions